# subsetting within function in r - always return the first factor of the selected variable

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I want to subset data in a function I wrote, but I keep running into the same issue that the subsetted data is the one I wanted.

sample data:

```
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
QID = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(n, QID, b) 
df$QID = as.character(df$QID)
str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ n: num  2 3 5
 $ QID: chr  "aa" "bb" "cc"
 $ b: logi  TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

The function I wrote is that I need to first subset the data inside the function and then proceed.

```
testFun = function(QID){
   QofInterest = subset(data, QID == String(QID))
   ...
return(QofInterest)
}
```

But it always returns the data with the first char value. For example, if I do:

```
dataWanted = testFun("bb")
```

it will always return me the row with QID == "aa"

I am not sure why this is happening. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add the packages you are using. I can't find the `String` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear why `String` is needed and from which package it is used.  Simply

```
testFun = function(str1){
   subset(df, QID == str1)

 }

testFun('bb')
#  n QID     b
#2 3  bb FALSE
```

returns the expected rows

Comment: thanks! but can you tell me why String is not necessary here?

Comment: @lalalulu  The input to the function i.e. `'bb'` is already a string

Comment: but why would using String(QID) make this function always return the first value? Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @lalalulu  From where did you get the `String` function.